# Better way to ensure a method logic executed once without boolean flag

Tags: c#, design-patterns

This is a way to execute Dosomething logic once using flag. (C# code and Update is always called once per frame.) 
And it's not so complicated, simple, very plain and well used way.

```
class Monster {
    bool isCalled = false;
    float energy = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        energy += Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        if((isCalled == false) && (energy>100.0f))
        {
            isCalled = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }

    void DoSomething(){}
}
```

But, I think the management of boolean flag is a kind of tiresome task.
 So I am trying to find better alternatives.
Is there any better or elegant way to do this (executing Dosomething once) without boolean flag?
For example, another design pattern's way, etc.

Comment: Why not put `Update` call into constructor?

Comment: Depends on `DoSomething`, maybe what you do can store this action. However, you have to store somewhere that it's already done. If you want to make it even simpler you could provide a `HasToBeDone` method that checks the energy and the flag.

Comment: Geh, was typing that @TimSchmelter \o/

Comment: look at the State Pattern

Comment: Whatever pattern you choose, please decorate your DoSomething with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] (or lock in the method body yourself). Because it is critical to have it invoked only once, you should make sure it is not accessed by two threads at the same time because of a race condition.

Comment: yep, if it's multi threads. but my case is single thread. thanks for commenting. : )

Comment: you can make your condition simpler. `!isCalled && energy > 100.0f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dedicated well-named *boolean flag* is clear and common pattern.

Often you don't need dedicated flag, e.g. old singleton patterns doesn't use `bool`, but rather testings *special value*:

```
if(instance == null)
{
    .. // do something
}
```

Logic is clear enough as you can see. People often use other special values to avoid necessity of introducing flag: `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, `double.IsNaN`, negative value, etc.

Important is to have intentions clear, don't obscure logic with too many small details. If there are too many things to take care about - rather introduce a dedicated flag.

In your case you may want to start using [state-machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) more obviously, because I'd assume what `Monster` can be in many different states which influence what various methods do:

```
class Monster
{
    enum States { NotInitialized, Dead, Normal, EnergyMax, ... }
    States _state;
    float _energy;

    void Update()
    {
        _energy += Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        switch(_state)
        {
            case States.Normal:
                if(_energy > EnergyMax)
                {
                    DoSomething(); // called once when energy become max
                    _state = States.EnergyMax;
                }
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather *combine* all such flags into a single `enum`, like that:

```
class Monster {
  [Flags]
  private enum Status {
    Updated,
    Called,
    Killed,  
    ... 
  }

  private Status status;

  void Update() {
    if ((status & Status.Updated) == Status.Updated)
      return;

    try {
      ....
    }
    finally {
      status |= Status.Updated;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: `status.HasFlag(Status.Updated)` is slightly more clear than combination of `&` and `==`. Otherwise [flag field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_field) is a good idea to use in place of many *boolean flags*, which your example demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always replace `DoSomething` with NOP action once it is executed:

```
class Monster {
    float energy = 0.0f;
    Action onUpdate;

    public Monster()
    {
        onUpdate = DoSomething;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        onUpdate();
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        energy += Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        if(energy > 100.0f)
        {
            // whatever you need to do
        }
        onUpdate = () => {};
    }
}
```

However, I believe that most developers are accustomed to using boolean flag to track this, and you might get less raised eyebrows if you go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Monster
{
    private Action _doSomething;

    public Monster()
    {
        _doSomething = DoSomething;
    }

    float energy = 0.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        energy += Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        if (energy > 100.0f)
            if (_doSomething != null)
                _doSomething();
    }

    void DoSomething() 
    {
        // logic...
        _doSomething = null;
    }
}
```

**But still i think a flag is a better practice.** Something has to be toggled. a flag/reference..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the state pattern like this:

```
class Monster
    {
        float energy = 0.0f;
        DoSomethingState state;

        public Monster()
        {
            this.state = new DoSomethingStateNotCalled(this);
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            energy += Random.Range(0f, 1f);
            this.state.Update();
        }

        public void DoSomething() {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("done something");
        }

        public float GetEnergy() {
            return this.energy;
        }

        public void SetState(DoSomethingState state) {
            this.state = state;
        }
    }

abstract class DoSomethingState {

        protected Monster Monster;

        public DoSomethingState(Monster monster) {
            this.Monster = monster;
        }

        public abstract void Update();
    }

class DoSomethingStateCalled : DoSomethingState
    {
        public DoSomethingStateCalled(Monster monster)
            : base(monster)
        {
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
        }
    }

 class DoSomethingStateNotCalled : DoSomethingState
    {
        public DoSomethingStateNotCalled(Monster monster)
            : base(monster)
        {
        }

        public override void Update()
        {
            if (this.Monster.GetEnergy() > 100.0f)
            {
                this.Monster.DoSomething();
                this.Monster.SetState(new DoSomethingStateCalled(this.Monster));
            }
        }
    }
```